# Replication and memory leak

Tags: jpa, memory-leaks, ejb, weblogic, replication

Memory leaks in weblogic server.

The memory of our server becomes saturated every day and we are called to make a daily reboot. 
    In the code, there is nothing special that saturates the memory. However, a heap dump shows that the classes that occupy more memory are

```
weblogic.management.mbeanservers.internal.MBeanCICInterceptor (retained heap 5376058)
 and the weblogic.cluster.replication.ReplicationManager class (retained heap 2690546).
```

weblogic.xml :

`<session-descriptor> 
      <cookie-name> OURPROJECT_SESSIONID </cookie-name> 
      <persistent-store-type> replicated_if_clustered</persistent-store-type>

</session-descriptor>`

Is it possible that the fact of putting in configuration in weblogic.xml can cause memory leaks?

Answer (score 0):

There is a know issue at Oracle with MBeanCICInterceptor which causes a memory leak with WebLogic Server 12.2.1.2
If you are running this version you can apply PSU 180717 and the apply path 27469756

If you are running another version open a SR at Oracle support.

Comment: Thank you a lot for your answer . But I would like de verify if that problem exists already for weblogic 12.1 because in fact our application was deployed on 12.1 and we have recently migrated to 12.2.1.2 and that memory leak problem exists in the 2 cases.Any idea?

Comment: You should contact Oracle support about your issue.  The bug was opened for 12.2.1.2 and does not mention 12.1.x but that does not necessarily mean that the bug does not exist under 12.1.x